# Where is my JDK?

Tags: java

I installed Oracle Java 1.8 using ppa. When I list java alternatives, I can only see 1.8 JRE! But when I do
`javac -version`
I can see 
`javac 1.8.0_05`

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1073      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1072      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1073      manual mode
```

Here is what I see when I run 
`sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

```
  Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac   1073      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac   1072      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac   1073      manual mode
```

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

I can only see 1.8 JRE in Eclipse and not 1.8 JDK. What am I missing? I want to be able to create a Java project targeting JDK 1.8.
It looks like I have `javac` setup fine but why does it not show up in Eclipse in the list of JDK?

Comment: You might want to try `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` instead. The JDK is likely to be located in `/usr/lib/jvm/`.

Comment: I added results of this command in the question.

Comment: OP downloaded another version of eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my Eclipse version was not yet supporting JDK 1.8! Downloaded a supported, newer version and I can now target 1.8 for my project.